# onclick function is not repeating inside javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to repeat a jquery function dynamically for n-numner of times. Alert is working for the number of count but function is not created as many times.
My code is as below

```
        var count = 5;
        var i = 1;
        for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            var min = ".min" + i;
            alert(min); // Just for testing purpose, working good
            document.writeln(min); // Just for testing purpose, working good
            alert(i); // Just for testing purpose, working good

            // Following function does not get repeated, 
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("min" + i).click(function () {
                    alert(i);
                });
            });
        }
```

My body section code is as follows

```
 <div class="min1"> Test - 1 </div>
 <div class="min2"> Test - 2 </div>
 <div class="min3"> Test - 3 </div>
 <div class="min4"> Test - 4 </div>
```

This may look simple but I need someone's guide to get it done. Please help me to make it work. This is just a concept which I am going to implement on a large basis in my project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your function won't work as you have missed the dot selector as in $("min"+i)

Comment: `$("min" + i)` What purpose does that selector serve?

Comment: When I view the source code in the browser, I find no repeat in the function. So that error related to dot should although be corrected but priority is to get it repeated so that individual function can target individual div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the problem in your code is the wrong use of [closure in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

The solution can be different, you can use a common click handler for all the elements then use a `data-*` attribute to store the dynamic value that is needed in the click handler.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".min").click(function() {
    alert($(this).data('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="min1 min" data-id="1">Test - 1</div>
<div class="min2 min" data-id="2">Test - 2</div>
<div class="min3 min" data-id="3">Test - 3</div>
<div class="min4 min" data-id="4">Test - 4</div>
```